# How to edit a docker image and deploy it

Tags: image, docker, ubuntu-14.04

I want to install custom programs on an ubuntu 14.04 image using docker and then upload the result to a repository online. Is there a guide somewhere that can point me to the right direction ?

Comment: There are *lots* of guides, including a variety of documentation on the docker website itself.  What have you looked at so far?

Comment: this: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/baseimages/

Comment: and this: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/

Comment: probably it's because i'm too  new to the tecnology, but i can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

you create a Dockerfile that starts with ...

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
# Other commands here e.g.
# RUN apt-get -y install apache2
CMD bash
```

THEN create an account on docker hub

https://hub.docker.com/

THEN you can ...

```
docker build ... etc
```

to build your image

THEN to test it, create a container with ...

```
docker run ... etc
```

THEN finally, when happy with it ...

```
docker login
docker push ... etc
```

Once pushed, you can pull from any server with ...

```
docker login
docker pull
```

Obviously, you need docker installed on every server you are pulling from

Comment: hum, can't i like run an ubuntu image, install all the custom components i need and when i'm done save it somehow and deploy it ?

Comment: Yes it's possible but it isn't the recommended approach. Here you can take a look: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/ .
It's possible to start your ubuntu container from the ubuntu image. Perform your installations and commit the container as an image. But like already said it's recommended to perform the installation steps in a dockerfile where you start from ubuntu (like @danday74 explained)

Comment: docker hub is not needed at all to use Dockerfiles.

Comment: noone said it was - docker hub is used to push to and pull from if needed - and saves building images from a dockerfile all the time